# A function is a.e. equal to a polynomial.

Tags: measure-theory, limits, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Let $f\in{L^p}$. For $t>0$, let $P_{t,n}(x)$ be a collection of polynomials of degree less then or equal to $n$ in the variable $x$ and the family is given by $t$ such that $P_{t,n}(x)\rightarrow{f(x)}$ as $t\downarrow{0}$, then can we conclude $f$ is (a.e) to a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$? In fact is $lim_{t\downarrow 0}P_{t,n}(x)$ a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only approximate an $L^p(Ω)$ function by a polynomial sequence if the domain $Ω$ is a pre-compact set (if not, no polynomial will be in that space), and to be meaningful, of Lebesgue-measure greater than zero.

Then the coefficients of the polynomial $p$ can be obtained from the moments $\int_Ω x^k\,p(x)\,dx$ of the polynomial. And since the moments are, by Hölders inequality, continuous functions on $L^p(Ω)$, the coefficients of $p_{t,n}$ must converge if the $p_{t,n}$ converges to $f$.

If $p$ denotes the limit polynomial formed from the limits of the coefficients, it is then easy to see that $\|p_{t,n}-p\|_p$ converges to zero, and consequently, that $\|p-f\|_p=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In case the domain for all the functions is  a compact interval then Weierstrass theorem about continuous functions being uniform limit of polynomials will contradict this.

Comment: How does it contradict and you mean $lim_{{t}\downarrow{0}}P_{t,n}(x)$ cannot be a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: I don't see anything contradicts to Weierstrass Theorem at all.

Comment: Take a nowhere differentiable continuous function, for example.

Comment: But the assumption is that there already exists an approximating sequence of polynomials. That is, $\|p_{t,n}-f\|_p\to 0$ for $t\to0$ is given, so counter-examples of not polynomially approachable functions are excluded.